How to calculate the norm of $L^p(L^2(T,d\mu),L^2(T,d\mu))$?
I meet a problem when solving Exercise 5.6.2 of L.Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis(3rd Edition). Here is the question:
Ex. 5.6.2  Let $(T,d\mu)$ be a $\sigma-$finite measure space. For every $t\in T$, let $R(t)$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with sides parallel to the axes such that the map $t\mapsto R(t)$ is measureable. Then there is a constant $C_n>0$ such that for all $1<p<\infty$ and for all families of square integrable functions $\{f_t\}_{t\in T}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $t\mapsto f_t(x)$ is measureable for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$
\biggl\|\biggl(\int_T|(\widehat{f_t}\chi_{R(t)})^{\vee}|^2d\mu(t)\biggr)^{\frac{1}{2}}\biggr\|_{L^p}\le C_n\max(p,(p-1)^{-1})^n\biggl\|\biggl(\int_T|f_t|^2d\mu(t)\biggr)^{\frac{1}{2}}\biggr\|_{L^p}.
$$
In hint he writes: When $n=1$ reduce matters to an $L^p(L^2(T,d\mu),L^2(T,d\mu))$ inequality for the Hilbert transform...
Here is my question: By the definition of $L^p(X,\mathscr{B})$, I know that
$$
L^p(X,\mathscr{B}):=\{\mathscr{B}\mbox{-measureable functions }F:(\int_X\|F(x)\|_{\mathscr{B}}^pd\mu(x))^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty\}.
$$
But when discussing $L^p(L^2(T,d\mu),L^2(T,d\mu))$, the integration seems to be like
$$
\int_{L^2(T,d\mu)}\|F\|_{L^2(T,d\mu)}^2d\mu
$$
$\|F\|_{L^2(T,d\mu)}$ is easy to understand, but how to understand and compute $\int_{L^2(T,d\mu)}$? If the integration region be a function space, I tend to regard the integration result as a function, but the definition seems to require the result of integration above shall be a number. How to explain this?

What does it mean for the map $t \mapsto R(t)$ to be measurable?

I think it means that for all $t\in T$, rectangle $R(t)$ is a measureable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I believe what Grafakos means by exhibiting an $L^p(L^2(T), L^2(T))$ inequality of the Hilbert transform is exactly the previous inequality you wrote but with the Hilbert transform, i.e.
$$\left \| \left( \int_T |H(f_t)|^2 \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right\|_p \leq C \left \| \left( \int_T |f_t|^2 \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right\|_p$$
As the hint mentions, reducing to this case should be fairly easy, since we already know that for a given interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, then multiplying by the characteristic function of this interval in Fourier space can be nicely represented as a conjugation of the Hilbert transform with $M^a$ and $M^b$, namely
$$ (\chi_{[a,b]} \hat{f})\check{} = \frac{i}{2}(M^aHM^{-a} - M^bHM^{-b})(f) $$
where $M^a(f)(x) = e^{2 \pi i ax}f(x)$ ( and it is very easy to check that $M^a: L^p(\mathbb{R}, L^2(T, d\mu)) \to L^p(\mathbb{R}, L^2(T, d\mu))$ is bounded, meaning it satisfies the inequality written above)
For proving this inequality when $p = 2$, because the power of $\frac{1}{2}$ inside our $L^p$ norm will disappear, we can swap integrals using Tonelli's, and then use the fact that, for any $f_t \in L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$, that $\|H(f_t)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})}^2 \leq C \|f_t\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})}^2$ (since the Hilbert transform is $L^p$ bounded for $1 < p < \infty$). Swapping integrals again using Tonelli's will yield the desired inequality for $p = 2$.
To extend from $p = 2$ to all $1 < p < \infty$, we need to apply theorem 5.6.1 (a theorem about $L^p$ boundedness of Banach-valued singular integral operators) - at first it might seem confusing, but it is really not difficult once you develop some greater comfort working with these more abstract objects. To apply this theorem, we need to find a kernel $\overrightarrow{K}(x): \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\} \to L(L^2(T, d\mu), L^2(T, d\mu))$ such that 3 conditions hold (as in Grafakos' notation, here $L(\mathcal{B}_1, \mathcal{B}_2)$ denotes the space of bounded linear operators between two Banach spaces, $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$):

(Size condition) $\|\overrightarrow{K}(x)\|_{L^2(T) \to L^2(T)} \leq \frac{A_1}{|x|} $

(Generalized Hormander's) $\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}} \int_{|x| \geq 2|y|} \|\overrightarrow{K}(x - y) - \overrightarrow{K}(x)\|_{L^2(T) \to L^2(T)} \, dx \leq A_2$

(Existence of singular integral) There should exist some sequence $\{\varepsilon_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $\lim_{k \to \infty} \varepsilon_k = 0$ along with a bounded operator $\overrightarrow{K_0} \in L(L^2(T), L^2(T))$ such that
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty}\left\| \overrightarrow{K_0} - \int_{1 \geq |x| >  \varepsilon_k} \overrightarrow{K}(x)\, dx  \right\|_{L^2(T) \to L^2(T)} = 0$$ (note that this is an $L^2(T)$-valued integral)


and lastly (and personally what I found to be the most confusing), we need $\overrightarrow{K}$ to be defined such that for any element $\{f_t\}_{t \in T} \in L^p(\mathbb{R}, L^2(T, d\mu))$, for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then
$$  \left\{ p.v. \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overrightarrow{K}(y)[f_t(x - y)]\, dy \right\}_{t \in T} = \{H(f_t)\}_{t \in T} = \left\{ p.v. \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{f_t(x - y)}{y}\, dy \right\}_{t \in T}$$
It is important to emphasize that we come to the above conclusion because of the fact that we are now trying to show the Hilbert transform is bounded from $L^p(\mathbb{R}, L^2(T, d\mu)) \to L^p(\mathbb{R}, L^2(T, d\mu))$, hence we know have to think about how the Hilbert transform acts on elements $\{f_t\}_{t \in T} \in L^p(\mathbb{R}, L^2(T, d\mu))$; this is where the $\{H(f_t)\}_{t \in T}$ comes from in the equalities above. But once we see that we need the above equality to hold, it is almost trivial to note that we need, for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$, that
$$ \overrightarrow{K}(x)(f_t(\cdot)) =  \dfrac{f_t(\cdot)}{x}$$. It is easy to check that for any fixed $x$, that by this definition, $\overrightarrow{K}(x)$ is a bounded operator from $L^2(T, d\mu) \to L^2(T, d\mu)$, having operator norm $\|\overrightarrow{K}(x)\|_{L^2(T) \to L^2(T)} = \frac{1}{|x|}$, which guarantees our size condition holds.
To check Hormander's is also quite easy, just note that for any $y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ and any $x$ satisfying $|x| \geq 2|y|$, then given $f_t \in L^2(T, d\mu)$, we see
$$(\overrightarrow{K}(x - y) - \overrightarrow{K}(x))(f_t(\cdot)) = \dfrac{f_t(\cdot)}{x - y} - \dfrac{f_t(\cdot)}{x} = f_t(\cdot)\dfrac{y}{x(x - y)} = \overrightarrow{K}(\dfrac{x(x-y)}{y})(f_t) $$
But given $|x| \geq 2|y|$, we see that
$$ |x(x-y)| = |x^2 - yx| \geq |x|^2 - |y||x| \geq |x|^2 - \frac{|x|}{2}|x| = \frac{|x|^2}{2}$$, so we see for any fixed $y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$, that
$$ \int_{|x| > 2|y|} \| \overrightarrow{K}(\dfrac{x(x-y)}{y})\|_{L^2(T) \to L^2(T)}\, dx =  \int_{|x| > 2|y|} \dfrac{|y|}{|x^2 - xy|}\, dx \leq 2|y| \int_{x > 2|y|} \dfrac{2}{|x|^2} \, dx = 4|y| [\frac{1}{2|y|}] = 2$$
Taking the supremum will exhibit Hormander's condition. I will then leave it for you to check the last condition, which will complete the proof for the $n = 1$ case.
